# Конвертация кириллицы из QByteArray в QString

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется функция, служащая для перевода массива bit'ов в строки (один элемент QVector'а соответствует одному символу).

```
QVector<QString> SignalHandler::BitToStr(QVector<QByteArray> message)
{
    QVector<QString> reconstructedMessage;
    QVector<QByteArray> hexByteArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i){
        hexByteArray.append(QByteArray::number(message[i].toInt(), 16));
    }

    return reconstructedMessage;
}
```

Для начала хочу перевести это счастье в hex, однако кириллические символы в упор не переводятся.

Вот что получается. Символы после `[3]` кириллические.

[image: Вид в отладчике]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как конвертировать QByteArray, содержащий кириллицу или другой текст в QString зависит от используемой кодировки (как текст  в виде байт закодирован). К примеру, если QByteArray содержит текст в utf-8 кодировке, то можно его напрямую в [QString() конструктор передать](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8):

```
QString u{utf8bytes}; // implicit QString::fromUtf8()
```

Если используется кодировка из текущей локали: [`QString::fromLocal8Bit(locale_bytes)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLocal8Bit).

Если кодировка задана по имени, [можно QTextCodec использовать](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#codecForName):

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
u = codec->toUnicode(cp1251_bytes);
```

Вот полный пример кода, который показывает как Unicode текст можно в байты превратить, используя различные кодировки. И как эти байты назад в текст преобразовать:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextCodec>

int main()
{
  // unicode to bytes
  QString s{QStringLiteral(u"мир")};
  QByteArray utf8bytes = s.toUtf8();
  qDebug() << utf8bytes;
  QByteArray locale_bytes = s.toLocal8Bit(); // result may be undefined
  qDebug() << locale_bytes; // same as utf8bytes in my case (C.UTF-8 locale)
  QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
  QByteArray cp1251_bytes = codec->fromUnicode(s);
  qDebug() << cp1251_bytes;

  // bytes to unicode
  QString u{utf8bytes}; // implicit QString::fromUtf8()
  qDebug() << u;
  qDebug() << QString::fromLocal8Bit(locale_bytes);
  qDebug() << codec->toUnicode(cp1251_bytes);
}
```

Чтобы собрать, добавьте в `<name>.pro`, сгенерированный по умолчанию с помощью `qmake -project` команды:

```
 CONFIG += c++11
```

---

В коде в вопросе какая-то странная схема кодирования текста используется. Судя по имени, каждый QByteArray содержит байты, соответствующие `"0"`, `"1"` символам в ASCII кодировке, то есть крайне неэффективное представление последовательности бит. Каждая последовательность бит, судя по значению кодирует номер символа (unicode code point или utf-16 code unit -- по данным не ясно). К примеру, первые 6 элементов в `QVector<QByteArray>` кодируют текст: `12GЖйц`:

```py
>>> codepoints = ["110001", "110010", "1000111", "10000010110", "10000111001", "10001000110"]
>>> [chr(int(bits, 2)) for bits in codepoints]
['1', '2', 'G', 'Ж', 'й', 'ц']
```

Если биты у вас кодируют utf-16 code unit, то можно использовать [`bits.toInt(nullptr, 2)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toInt) (или если code point, то [`QByteArray::toLong()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toLong)). Чтобы последовательность utf-16 code units превратить в текст, можно использовать [QString::fromUtf16()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf16-1):

```
QByteArray bits{"10000010110"};
char16_t utf16codeunit = bits.toInt(nullptr, 2);
char16_t str[] = {utf16codeunit, 0};
u = QString::fromUtf16(str);
qDebug() << u; // -> "Ж"
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не касаться общей эффективности приведенного фрагмента кода (почему символы передаются в виде массива символов с бинарным их представлением - не понятно), то проблема кроется в вызове

```
message[i].toInt()
```

который преобразует строку с текстовым представлением числа в само это число. Основание системы счисления по умолчанию - 10 (что уже не правильно - вам нужно 2). Почему длинные последовательности не преобразовываются - потому что их бинарное представление (с учетом того, что строки интерпретируются как десятичные) не влезает в int. Для получения требуемого эффекта нужно заменить указанный вызова на

```
message[i].toInt(nullptr, 2)
```

Comment: Символы передаются так, потому что по используемому каналу связи я могу передавать только биты.

Comment: @Alexander Zolkin, Да, но вы каждый из этих бит потом конвертите в полноценный байт со значением 48 (ASCII код цифры 0) или 49 (ASCII код цифры 1). А вместо этого лучше было бы объединить эти биты в слово с помощью побитовых операций и операций сдвига, а потом уже это значение дальше обрабатывать. Впрочем, не знаю. Может вы их именно в таком виде и получаете. Но тогда это странно. Налицо ненужная избыточность протокола.